# about generating an image for a random matrix with large dimensions

Tags: r

I have a matrix, whose entries can be -1, 0, or 1. I am trying to use the color to differentiate these different values, since most of them are 0. I use the following code

```
 x<-y<-seq(1:10)
 xcolor<-c("purple3", "green" , "red")
 image(x,y,DiffMatrix,col=xcolor)
```

For illustration purposes, the DiffMatrix is a 10*10 matrix,

> [1,] 1   0  0   0        0     1     1      -1        0      0
>
> [2,] 1   0  0   0       -1     1     1       1        0      0
>
> [3,] 1   0  0   0        0     1     0       0        0      0
>
> [4,] 1   0  0   0        0     1     0       0        0      0
>
> [5,] 1   0  0   0        0     0     0       0        0      0
>
> [6,] 1   0  0   0       -1     1     0       1        0      0
>
> [7,] 1   0  0   0        0     0     0       0        0      0
>
> [8,] 1   0  1   0        0     1     0       0        0      0
>
> [9,] 1   0  0   0        0     0     0       0        0      0
>
> [10,] 0   0  0   0        0     0     0       0        0      0

The generated image is this

[image]

My question is, if the matrix becomes very big, like 2000*3000. The resolution of the generated figure using the above approach will be very low. Are there any graphical approaches for showing the distributions of these different values: I want to see how many “1” are occurred in the matrix, and which positions are associated with “1”; which positions are associated with “0”,etc.

Comment: There are a number of things you might try. What about histograms for each colour by row? And then by column? This alone would give you a nice idea of the distribution.

Comment: Another obvious way: there are only three values. You could do three images of the same matrix side by side, where all but one of the values are white in each image.

Comment: For large arrays of data,  `rasterImage` will plot a lot faster

Answer (score 0):

If you've got relatively high-density,  consider plotting `points` and assigning partially transparent colors to your values.  In this way, where there are many "1"s, for example, the points will overlap and darken the image.

The easiest way to assign such colors, once you get used to it :-),  is to set the colors in hex:  `some_color<- #0F66F088`, where the first three pairs identify the intensity of RGB, and the last pair identifes the transparency.  There are several examples somewhere in the StackOverflow archives, but I forget where :-(